# How to sort all rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Let's say, I have data below in dataframe and I want to put the value in "Value1" if "Value2" is less than "Value1".

Basically I just need to sort the value of columns.
Target output:

```
    Value1  Value2
0   K   Z
1   2   13
2   5   81
3   7   L
4   A   A
5   D   D
6   C   C
7   G   G
8   K   K
9   1   21
```

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Value1':['Z', '2', '81', '7','A', 'D', 'C','G','K','21'],
        'Value2':['K', '13', '5', 'L','A', 'D', C','G','K','1']}
Exp =pd.DataFrame(data)
ExpRowCnt = Exp.shape[0]
rangeIdx = list(range(0,ExpRowCnt))
valueSort = Exp.sort_values(rangeIdx, axis=1)

print(Exp)
```

.....

```
  Value1 Value2
0      Z      K
1      2     13
2     81      5
3      7      L
4      A      A
5      D      D
6      C      C
7      G      G
8      K      K
9     21      1
[Finished in 5.2s]
```

Can anyone help me to achieve my target output.
TIA..

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you make a question try to give a minimum information: input sample (ok), expected output sample (ok), what did you try (just giving a code with not trials...), research (?). SO is not a free coding/debugging service.

Comment: `m = Exp['Value1'] > Exp['Value2']; Exp.loc[m, ['Value1', 'Value2']] = Exp.loc[m, ['Value2', 'Value1']].values`

Comment: Are the numbers in your DataFrame strings or ints? This will affect the comparison, e.g.: `2 > 13` -> `False`, `'2' > '13'` -> `True`. How are you comparing `7` and `L`?

Comment: @Dan due to initialization `data = {'Value1':['Z', '2', '81', '7','A',..` all are string

Comment: @splash58 I'm not sure that's what OP wants, the expected output is sorted according to int sorting, not string sorting.